# tabulate variables created on the fly

Tags: stata

I often want to tabulate the product of two variables.  For example, suppose that I have `x1` and `x2`, both of which are integer-valued.  In R, `table(x1 * x2)` does what I want.  I don't need to create a new variable (say, `x3`) to get the information that I need.

I want to do the same in Stata.  That is, I want to run a command like `tabulate x1*x2`.  (I need to do this sort of thing all the time, which is one reason why I don't first want to create a new variable `x3`.)  Is there a way to do this in Stata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can get this kind of behavior without some programming effort. Notice that `tabulate` requires *varnames* or *varlists*, and *expressions* are not allowed. See `help tabulate`. Naturally, `generate` is a command that does allow *expressions*. See `help exp` for some details.

I recall a discussion along the lines of "on-the-fly computations" in Statalist but I'm not able to find it right now; you might want to check the [archives](http://stata.com/statalist/archive/). If I recall correctly, this was not possible for things other than factor variables which you can use "on-the-fly" with *factor variable notation* (`help factor variables`). I remember there were good reasons for why this is the case.

But for something like the product of two variables you could write a simple program in an .ado file, save it in a Stata system directory (preferably ~/ado/personal/) and then use it whenever you like.

Here is an example program:

```
program define tabulate2, byable(recall)

    /* 
    Tabulate the product of two variables.
    Modeled after the official -tab1- command.
    */

    version 12
    syntax varlist(min=2 max=2 numeric) [if] [in] [, *]

    tokenize `varlist'

    tempvar prod
    gen `prod' = `1' * `2'
    label var `prod' "`1' x `2'"

    tempvar touse
    mark `touse' `if' `in'

    capture noisily tabulate `prod' if `touse', `options'

end
```

And some code that makes use of the newly defined command `tabulate2`:

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
var1 var2
1 2
3 4
3 4
3 4
5 6
end

list

tabulate2 var1 var2
```

The output:

```
. tabulate2 var1 var2

var1 x var2 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          2 |          1       20.00       20.00
         12 |          3       60.00       80.00
         30 |          1       20.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          5      100.00
```

Not perfect, but I hope you get the idea.

See also `help program` and references therein.

Comment: I think Roberto is correct. In order to tabulate a product in Stata, you must calculate that product first. There is no way round that except by hiding the calculation in a program. As you want to do it repeatedly, the program should be useful.

Comment: Thanks so much @NickCox. I've incorporated your suggestion of adding the variable label to the `program` in order to get rid of the ugly temporary variable name. Specifically: ``label var `prod' "`1' x `2'"``.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer: thank you for an exceptionally helpful solution.  It's what I am going to use.